# Expected expression before '{' token in Macro

Tags: c

I already researched what the problem could be but I didn't find any good explanation.

I have to program a Macro that returns a number mod 2 but I always get the Error: expected expression before '{' token for every line in that I call the Macro
My current Header is as follows:

```
#define MOD2(number)       \
    {                    \
        return (number) % 2; \
    }
```

and the Main Code:

```
int main(){
   int number = 255;
   printf("%d mod 2 ist %d.\n", number, MOD2(number));
   printf("%d mod 2 ist %d.\n", number, MOD2(number + 1));
   printf("%d mod 2 ist %d.\n", number, MOD2(number + 2));
   printf("%d mod 2 ist %d.\n", number, MOD2(number + 3));
}
```

Can someone please explain what the problem is?

Comment: Change the definition with `#define MOD2(number) (number) % 2`

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to define a macro as if it's a function, which it is not.  Macros do direct token substitution, so this:

```
printf("%d mod 2 ist %d.\n", number, MOD2(number));
```

Gets translated to:

```
printf("%d mod 2 ist %d.\n", number, { return (number) % 2; });
```

Which is invalid syntax.  You instead want:

```
#define MOD2(number) ((number) % 2)
```

Comment: Ahhh. Okay Thank you very much :D

Comment: @5T0RMBR34K3R Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your macro will turn

```
printf("%d mod 2 ist %d.\n", number, MOD2(number));
```

into

```
printf("%d mod 2 ist %d.\n", number, {return (number) % 2;});
```

which should be clearly in error.